# Strophe and Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with xmpp connection in Phonegap using Strophe. I try to implement strophe plugin from web app to Phonegap app (jQuery Mobile) and when I try to connect, Strophe call Strophe.Status.CONNECTING, next "Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL", next Strophe.Status.CONNECTING and then nothing else. It isn't fired errors, send Stanza (with "body rid=xx....") but nothing happens. The stanzas, servers, ids, callers, etc run well in Web page with normal jQuery.

Has anybody worked with phonegap and strophe and can help me? The current project is under Android but it will be available on iOS, Windows Phone and BlackBerry and I would like to use a javascript native method.

Update:
I am trying with Android mobile phone and original site (site for desktop computers) and strophe isn't connect neither, with same behavior.

Comment: have you whitelisted the address of the xmpp server?

Comment: Yes, with **subdomains="true"** and **browserOnly="false"**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was strophe.flxhr.js and flxhr files, that isn't accept on mobile devices. Thank you @Vlad.

Comment: You dont need flxhr in phonegap, just include strophe.js and start coding. Check if you have allowed cors in config.xml